# How to create a table with a fixed column at the start and end?

Tags: html, css, html-table

So basically, I am trying to create a table with a fixed column at the start, and the end.

This is the layout:

```
Fixed      |   Header 1   |   Header 2   |   Header 3   |     Fixed    |
Col 1      |     Col 2    |     Col 3    |     Col 4    |     Col 5    |
Col 1      |     Col 2    |     Col 3    |     Col 4    |     Col 5    |
Col 1      |     Col 2    |     Col 3    |     Col 4    |     Col 5    |
Col 1      |     Col 2    |     Col 3    |     Col 4    |     Col 5    |
Col 1      |     Col 2    |     Col 3    |     Col 4    |     Col 5    |
Col 1      |     Col 2    |     Col 3    |     Col 4    |     Col 5    |
Col 1      |     Col 2    |     Col 3    |     Col 4    |     Col 5    |
```

So as the above example displays, the very first column and very last column needs to be fixed (always visible). The in-between must be scrollable (overflow-x: scroll), although I am not to sure how to approach this.

I have come up with this, which only makes the first column fixed. Although, it is not a reliable solution since it is messing up the layout on my page due to the `margin-left: -100px`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mJd2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dunno about old-ie, but this will work in modern browsers:

```
.last-td {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:100px;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
    margin-right: 120px;
}
```

Give the all the last `<td>`s `class="last-td"`. Or you could use `td:last-child`.

http://jsfiddle.net/s2dGX/

Comment: Very nice work around. Not to concerned about old IE. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, then what are the stars (`*margin-left: -100px;`) for?

Comment: Was taken from another example that was attempting something similar.

Comment: Oh, that explains it.